# Guzzle annotations not working with Doctrine2 annotation parser in Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've got a Symfony2 project and am trying to integrate the [GuzzleBundle](https://github.com/ddeboer/GuzzleBundle) to build a web service client. I'm using the `@guzzle` annotations for the client commands (which extend `Guzzle\Service\Command\AbstractCommand`).

It seems to work correctly in the dev environment but when I try to load pages using the prod environment I get a Doctrine `AnnotationException`:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException' with message '[Semantical Error] The annotation "@guzzle" in class Admin\FindAnExpertBundle\Entity\SymplecticClient\Rest\Command\UserById was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?'
```

I also get an error about a missing `Proxy` class file:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/httpd/sites/experts.admin/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/AdminFindAnExpertBundleEntityRelationshipTypeProxy.php) [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/httpd/sites/experts.admin/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php
```

I assume this is because the fatal error is stopping all the proxy classes from being created.

Guzzle appears not to use the Doctrine annotation parser so I'm wondering if there's a way to make it ignore `@guzzle` annotations or register them somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the classes relating to the web service client out of the Entity folder, which stopped the Doctrine annotation parser from reading them. In retrospect, the classes shouldn't have been in that folder anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the annotation-Parser of Guzzle, which handles the "@guzzle" annotation, e.g.:

```
use Guzzle\Service\Inspector as guzzle;
```

But i don't know which class it is.

Maybe [this gist file](https://gist.github.com/3074476) helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I had tried to find the class that was responsible for the guzzle annotations but didn't have any luck. I don't think the classes relating to the web service client should have been in the Entity folder anyway, in hindsight.